# Allowing a user to pick an option for how a program runs at the terminal

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

So, let's say I have two functions that do the same thing but with a different algorithm.  I want to allow the user to chose one option or the other at the terminal.

When the user choses which option they would like, it should go something like this...

```
./a.out option1
```

or

```
./a.out option2
```

I would read up on this more before I came here and asked, so maybe I could have some code but I don't even know what this is called so I could research it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look up "command line arguments", which ought to be covered in any basic C tutorial.

Comment: "I don't even know what this is called so I could research it!" -- Really? googling "C program options" immediately yields answers.

Comment: I had no idea to call that "c program options", which is why I posted it on here.  So yes, really.

Answer (score 1):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//E.g. ./a.out option1
//argc : 2
//argv[0] : "./a.out" (or It might be a different. E.g fullpath or "" or etc..)
//argv[1] : "option1"

    int opt = 0;
    if(argc > 1){
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "option1")==0)
            opt = 1;
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "option2")==0)
            opt = 2;
        else
            opt = -1;
    }
    switch(opt){
    case 0:
        printf("Option was not specified.\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Option 1 was specified.\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Option 2 was specified.\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Options that you specify are wrong.\n");
        printf("Usage : %s [option1 | option2]\n", argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks, I know this is a total noobie question but I'm switching my programming to command line from an IDE in hopes of getting better.  Thanks again!